# Why do classes use a helper for translation instead of $this?

Tags: localisation

In core modules and sometimes templates, I see helper classes being used for translation:

```
Mage::helper('someModule')->__('translate me');
```

Why is this preferable to:

```
$this->__('translate me');
```

Comment: Hey Brendan, this question is exceptionanlly good and I appreciate your effort. +1 for that. However Alanstorm give you a valid answer for your question. So it would be nice to accept an answer from available answers.  Thanks :-)

Comment: More power to you brother :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just theorizing, but when you call

```
$this->__('Foo')
```

in a template, which module's CSV translation file will Magento use to translate Foo?

It's not always clear which module's translation helper Magento will ultimately call to translate the string/key.  Since Magento allows you to use the same key in different modules for different strings, it's often important to know which module's translation data you're using. In fact, if a template is used across multiple modules, using `$this->__()` might be "considered harmful", as it would return different values depending on the block context the layout system used the template in.

My guess is the convenience helpers were added up front, but the developers building out the templates quickly starting instantiating helps so they knew which module's translation file would translate a string, and that pattern spread to the test of the framework.  This line of code, by itself, is ambiguous.

```
$this->__('Foo');
```

But you can be sure this line of code will use the `Mage_Catalog` localization information.

```
Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Foo')
```

Comment: Hmm, I get that logic. In practice I've only seen CSVs created within the frontend package for the active theme as /locale/{xyz}/translate.csv (not per module). I've had the "string exists in different modules and needs different translations" problem, but also "this string has multiple instances in this module and needs different translations" which the helpers don't resolve. Generally, I can probably stick with $this and one CSV per theme.

Comment: @BrendanFalkowski Yeah, it seems like a "module developer" vs. "theme developer" thing.  I'd say you're find using the built in helpers.

Comment: @AlanStorm definitely an upvote for you.

Answer (score 20):

Because you want to use an explicit module.

If you use `$this->__()` in a block context, the module of the block is used for translation. So if you want to use a special module, then you have to use `Mage::helper('mymodule')->__()`

Comment: In all cases, translations are tied to a certain module. When calling only $this, you are referring to the current module and when calling the long Mage::helper('mymodule')->__() you are translating the word with that module, just like a CSV from a module instead of the default CSV.

Comment: Correct. If you use a helper, you make it explicit.

Comment: What's the advantage of being explicit though? Translation CSVs don't distinguish between modules, or do they? Haven't heard of any hierarchy/inheritance fallback for them.

Comment: No, all the CSVs are merged, but you can have two different locations, due to the `Mage_Checkout::My Cart` syntax. And so it is important which module is used for translation

Comment: Aha, so helpers make a lot more sense for modules than they do in frontend packages, which only their own CSV overriding the core to contend with.

Answer (score 9):

Basically I'm going to say the same thing as the other guys said.
If you use `Mage::helper(...)` you make sure that a specific helper is used for translation.

For example let's take the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` block.

For the column headers there is this:  `'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),`.  if instead of the catalog helper `$this->__` would have been used, the text would have been translated using the `Mage_Adminhtml` module.

But this is a case where the logic behind using named helpers makes sense.

I just wanted to show a case where using `$this->__('..')` instead of the helper approach can lead to problems. I speak from experience.

Let's take the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs`. There is one line that looks like this:  `Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Home')`.

You would think that you are in the `catalog` module so you could use `$this` instead. But what if you override the block by your block called `Namespace_Module_Block_Breadcrumbs`?

If `$this` was used then the module used for translation would be `Namespace_Module` and you probably don't want that.

There are two options to avoid this. Either using a named helper as it already happens for most of the core blocks.

Or you as a developer can add this in the block class:

```
public function getModuleName() {
    return 'Mage_Catalog';
}
```

Then you are sure that all the texts using `$this->__` from your block (templates that render the block also included) are going to be translated using the catalog module.

Comment: Nice. The Breadcrumb theory was awesome.I loved it. +1 for that :-)

Answer (score 2):

One reason (which is just my perception), when you use helper you are more specific about the translation file, like `Mage::helper('catalog')` it will find the sentence in catalog file, while when you use `$this` it will randomly search in all the translation files. That's what I think.