# Small question to translation files

Tags: localisation

A module created a translation file in `app/locale/en_US/preorder.csv`.

I copied this file to `app/locale/de_DE/preorder.csv` but when I use `$this->__("xxx")` in the said module and have `"xxx","yyy"` in the preorder.csv file in de_DE it does not get translated. When I put `"xxx","yyy"` in Mage_Customer.csv in the same de_DE directory it gets translated.

So my question is, do I have to register new csv translation files somewhere? I thought all csv files in this directory will be taken.

Edit: When I rename the file like the modules: Webkul_Preorder.csv name then it works. SO magento does not take all CSV files in app/locale?

Comment: What class is `$this`. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33125/why-do-classes-use-a-helper-for-translation-instead-of-this

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not all files are read. The file must be registered in a module's config.xml and translations are then tied to this module's helper (except if developer mode is turned off and the translation string is globally unique), so you cannot override a translation of Mage_Customer in another module.

If that is what you want, you can override it in your theme in `app/design/[package]/[theme]/locale/de_DE/translate.csv` like this:

```
"Mage_Customer::xxx","yyy"
```